# Special Character in Azure appsettings

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, appsettings

Am hosting the API project in azure devops. I have set the connectionstring in the keyvault, passing the value to Appsettings. In the password,'&' character is present. Hence i set the password in connectionstring as 'Test&test', but upon fetching the value, connection string is breaking, and it is not taking '&' in password properly. I have been using YAML file for deploying the project.

Comment: Your question provides too little context to enable us to give you a detailed answer. Please refer to [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You should escape any special characters like the ampersand. To escape the `&` character, use `&amp;` instead of `&`. Your connection string should be

```
Test&amp;test
```